# Custom CSS: Custom padding

Tags: css, wordpress, padding

http://www.shaunhillphotography.co.uk/news/

I am trying to get 25px padding from the top of the white space to the first title. Trouble I have found so far is that if I apply styling to that title, it changes all of them which makes the rest look strange.

Conversely, on the front page of http://www.shaunhillphotography.co.uk/ I want to reduce the gap between the motto 'Love Life. Love Photography' and the image slider without messing up the styling on any of the other titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 25px padding from the top.  I would apply the padding to the #content-sm DIV.
2. Apply styling to the #post-110 DIV.

Comment: Shoot - sorry for the large text!  I must have hit a button!

Comment: I edited your answer to remove the big bold text. The `#` was setting the text as a title.

Comment: Brilliant, that did thew trick. Thank you!

#post-110{
        padding-top: 2px;
}

#content-sm{
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
        padding-top: 25px;
 padding-right: 0%;
}

Answer (score 0):

Add the padding to your container:

```
#container {
    padding-top: 25px;
}
```

For your second question, just remove the empty `<p>` between your title and the image slide.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up on the redundant <p> tag!